# xsd.exe code generator alternatives that can associate elements with simpleType restrictions

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

I have a XSD schema with a combination of the following restrictions and elements

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
...
<xsd:simpleType name="dollar11neg">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:pattern value="-?\d?\d?\d?\d?\d?\d?\d?\d\.\d\d"/>
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:element name="Price" type="dollar11neg"/>

<xsd:element name="Item">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
       <xsd:element ref="Price" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
...
```

XSD.exe does not generate the restrictions.. I am wondering if anyone knows of a tool that can generate a class that will include the restrictions.

The purpose of this is, during or before the serialization, if the field's value is in an incorrect format (missing decimal places), I can implement logic that will look at the required format for the value, and correct it base on the pattern restriction.

And I don't want to look through the whole xsd schema manually to find out what patterns are for each field and hard-code the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try the **XMLSPY** tool.

A free 30 day trial is available [here](http://www.altova.com/download/xmlspy/xml_editor_enterprise.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually prefer a free solution because I will be doing this continuously as the schema will be updated from time to time. Thanks for your quick response tho!